# Finding the smallest distance in a set of points from the origin

Tags: octave, distance

I am to find the smallest distance between a given set of points and the origin. I have a matrix with 2 columns and 10 rows. Each row represents coordinates. One point consists of two coordinates and I would like to calculate the smallest distance between each point and to the origin.  I would also like to determine which point gave this smallest distance.

In Octave, I calculate this distance by using `norm` and for each point in my set, I have a distance associated with them and the smallest distance is obviously the one I'm looking for.  However, the code I wrote below isn't working the way it should.

```
function [dist,koor] = bonus4(S)     
 S= [-6.8667,  -44.7967; 
    -38.0136, -35.5284; 
     14.4552, -27.1413; 
     8.4996,   31.7294; 
    -17.2183,  28.4815; 
    -37.5100,  14.1941; 
    -4.2664,  -24.4428; 
    -18.6655,  26.9427; 
    -15.8828,  18.0170; 
     17.8440, -22.9164]; 
    for i=1:size(S) 
        L=norm(S(i, :)) 

     dist=norm(S(9, :)); 
          koor=S(9, :) ; 
end
```

`i = 9` is the correct answer, but I need Octave to put that number in.  How do I tell Octave that this is the number I want?  Specifically:

```
 dist=norm(S(9, :));   
 koor=S(9, :);
```

I cannot use any packages. I found the geometry package online but I am to solve the task without additional packages.

Comment: you can't use packages but remember that it's all free software so you can look into the source and study it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll work off of your original code.  Firstly, you want to compute the norm of **all** of the points and store them as individual elements in an array.  Your current code isn't doing that and is overwriting the variable `L` which is a single value at each iteration of the loop.

You'll want to make `L` an array and store the norms at each iteration of the loop.  Once you do this, you'll want to find the location as well as the minimum distance itself.  That can be done with one call to [`min`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Utility-Functions.html#XREFmin) where the first output gives you the minimum distance and the second output gives you the location of the minimum.  You can use the second output to slice into your `S` array to retrieve the actual point.

Last but not least, you need to **define** `S` first before calling this function.  You are defining `S` inside the function and that will probably give you unintended results if you want to change the input into this function at each invocation.  Therefore, define `S` first, then call the function:

```
 S= [-6.8667,  -44.7967; 
    -38.0136, -35.5284; 
     14.4552, -27.1413; 
     8.4996,   31.7294; 
    -17.2183,  28.4815; 
    -37.5100,  14.1941; 
    -4.2664,  -24.4428; 
    -18.6655,  26.9427; 
    -15.8828,  18.0170; 
     17.8440, -22.9164];

function [dist,koor] = bonus4(S)             
    %// New - Create an array to store the distances
    L = zeros(size(S,1), 1);

    %// Change to iterate over number of rows
    for i=1:size(S,1) 
        L(i)=norm(S(i, :)); %// Change
    end

    [dist,ind] = min(L); %// Find the minimum distance
    koor = S(ind,:); %// Get the actual point
end
```

Or, make sure you save the above function in a file called `bonus4.m`, then do this in the Octave command prompt:

```
octave:1> S= [-6.8667,  -44.7967; 
>         -38.0136, -35.5284; 
>          14.4552, -27.1413; 
>          8.4996,   31.7294; 
>         -17.2183,  28.4815; 
>         -37.5100,  14.1941; 
>         -4.2664,  -24.4428; 
>         -18.6655,  26.9427; 
>         -15.8828,  18.0170; 
>          17.8440, -22.9164];
octave:2> [dist,koor] = bonus4(S);
```

Though this code works, I'll debate that it's slow as you're using a `for` loop.  A faster way would be to do this completely vectorized.  Because using `norm` for matrices is different than with vectors, you'll have to compute the distance yourself.  Because you are measuring the distance from the origin, you can simply square each of the columns individually then add the columns of each row.

Therefore, you can just do this:

```
S= [-6.8667,  -44.7967; 
    -38.0136, -35.5284; 
     14.4552, -27.1413; 
     8.4996,   31.7294; 
    -17.2183,  28.4815; 
    -37.5100,  14.1941; 
    -4.2664,  -24.4428; 
    -18.6655,  26.9427; 
    -15.8828,  18.0170; 
     17.8440, -22.9164]; 

function [dist,koor] = bonus4(S)     
    %// New - Computes the norm of each point
    L = sqrt(sum(S.^2, 2));

    [dist,ind] = min(L); %// Find the minimum distance
    koor = S(ind,:); %// Get the actual point

end
```

The function [`sum`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Sums-and-Products.html#XREFsum) can be used to sum over a dimension independently.  As such, by doing `S.^2`, you are squaring each term in the points matrix, then by using `sum` with the second parameter as `2`, you are summing over all of the columns for each row.  Taking the square root of this result computes the distance of each point to the origin, exactly the way the `for` loop functions.  However, this (at least to me) is more readable and I daresay faster for larger sizes of points.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate it! I have 2 little questions, though: if I create an m-file and run this line in octave:  `[dist,koor] = bonus4(S)` I get `dist = 24.01824    0.00000` and for `koor =  -15.8828   18.0170
   -6.8667  -44.7967` . Shouldn't I get just a scalar for dist? And, it seems like I get the places in the matrix where the smallest norm ist plus the  first row.

Comment: @PhilippLoipolt Yes, I made edits since the last time you commented.  The `L` matrix wasn't defined properly.  Please see the new edit by refreshing this page.

Comment: @PhilippLoipolt - Let me know if the above solution works for you. If it does and you no longer need help, please consider accepting my answer! That can be done by clicking on the checkmark icon at the top of my post, to the left below the up and down voting arrows. Good luck!

Comment: It does work. I have tested it and it seems to work. I have one last question: If I start octave.exe fresh and navitgate to the directory where the m-file sits, and run it - octave nags about elements not being defined. So I have to copy S into octave.exe, then run bonus4(S). Is there a way so taht octave gets the Matrix S directly out of the m-file? Because I need to put in other Matrices and run the mfile on different computers. Thank you so much, your help is very much appreciated and I will accept your answer.

Comment: Yes, you need to define `S` first, then run the function.  Therefore, run this command first: `S= [-6.8667,  -44.7967; 
    -38.0136, -35.5284; 
     14.4552, -27.1413; 
     8.4996,   31.7294; 
    -17.2183,  28.4815; 
    -37.5100,  14.1941; 
    -4.2664,  -24.4428; 
    -18.6655,  26.9427; 
    -15.8828,  18.0170; 
     17.8440, -22.9164];`, then do `[dist,koor] = bonus4(S);`.  **Make sure** you remove the `S` declaration in your function code. This should now do what you want.  You're getting that error because you aren't defining `S` first.  I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @PhilippLoipolt I've edited.  Have a look now.  Thanks for the accept!

Comment: just two small performance note. Instead of `sum (S.^2, 2)`, use `sumsq (S, 2)` which will be faster. Also, since you don't really need the distance, you only need them order by distance, there's no need to call `sqrt` at all. `min (sumsq (S, 2))` will do just fine.

Comment: @carandraug I have tried to run the code with those suggestions, but the output is incorrect (well, at least it does not what I want it to do). I actually do need the distance. (in this case it should be 24.018) With your changes I get  `[dist]=576.88` and `koor=-6.8667 -44.7967` which are the values of the first row in the matrix S. Why is that?

Comment: @carandraug Though `sumsq` is a nice addition, not "really needing the distance" is not true unfortunately.  The OP would like the actual Euclidean distance returned as part of the output arguments, so the actual definition with the square root is required.

Comment: @PhilippLoipolt Just take the square root of the result.  I'm also not sure why you're getting the first point.  Can you show me what you exactly changed?  If all else fails, just stick with our original edits.

Comment: I changed it from  `L = sqrt(sum(S.^2, 2));`  ;  to `L = min(sumsq(S, 2));` Also, if I have to take the sqareroot again anyways... I don't understand those changes at all? Also, since the Matrices I will run as a skript will never exeed 15 rows, I assume the performanceimprovement won't be noticeable in that case, would it?

Comment: @PhilippLoipolt remove the `min` part. Leave it where it was before and it'll work. As for the changes, yes this only would make a difference for larger sizes datasets. If you have only 15 rows, stick with what we have. No need to change.